# No Unity option while log in

Tags: 14.04, unity, desktop-environments

I am aware that there are some Unity related topics here. But my case is entirely different and I didn't notice it until recently that Unity is missing. I am using `Gnome Classic` and `Cinnamon` since a long time and have never bothered to check the existence of Unity in my system.

Recently I did a series of `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` after which most of my desktop environments like `Gnome Flashback` vanished. It must be around that time Unity disappeared to. The reason I noticed it now was the my laptop power went off as the battery was at zero and there was no warning in Cinnamon. I thought may using Unity would be able to sort things out and when checked found it was missing. It came as a surprise as I though being default it was there to stay.

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

from some AskUbuntu post on a search result. But even that couldn't pull me out of this.

How can I restore my Desktop?

Answer (score 2):

**Warning:** Ensure you've got another Desktop environment installed before your remove Unity!

Then install the Synaptic Package Manager:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

- then going to the dash:

  [image]
- Typing "Synaptic" <kbd>Enter</kbd>

  [image: Synaptic screen]
- Search for "Unity" in the filter
- Then remove Unity
- Again use filter
- Re-Install Unity

Comment: Could you please add the exact steps you took to accomplish this (so also a reputation 1 user can understand?)  **;-)**

Comment: Synaptic Package Manager > Search for " Unity " in filter > remove Unity >  Again use filter > Install Unity

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your answer is by [edit]ing it, with the edit button above to keep important information concentrated into the question itself instead of strewn all around the comments!  ;-)  (then leave a comment so I can come back and upvote!) **>:)**

Comment: @Fabby, thanks for the useful addition. The answer is clear, the comment is just an explanation.

Comment: See above!  No upvote, now...

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Install Ubuntu desktop and force a re-install

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```